# How to get data for given Dates range using MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Am having a set of JSON data stored in mongoDB collection by name "passengers". Here am uploading the raw data to DB using CSV file. In CSV file the "timestamp" column, it is given all dates as "12/1/2019 12:30" format.

I want to get the passengers data for given date range. But am not able to get the desired output. It is showing all dates instead of showing the dates between given range. The "timestamp" key in DB is of type "String"

For example

Am passing "fromDate" : "12/1/2019 09:00" and "toDate" : "12/3/2019 16:04" in body to server.

I want to get passengers details who travelled between dates "12/1/2019 09:00" to "12/3/2019 16:04" only, but it is showing all passengers from "12/1/2019 00:00" to "12/31/2019 00:00"

I tried with this :

```
passenger.find({
                'timestamp': {
                    $gte:req.body.fromDate,
                    $lt: req.body.toDate
                }
            }, function (err, passengersData) {
                console.log("Passenger details ==", passengersData);
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        "message": err.message
                    });
                    return;
                }
                res.status(200).json(passengersData);
            });
```

I want to get passengers details who travelled between dates "12/1/2019 09:00" to "12/3/2019 16:04" only, but it is showing all passengers from "12/1/2019 00:00" to "12/31/2019 00:00"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIEKx.png)

Comment: Why is it a string? Store date/time as a propper type! https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps

Comment: @raffis Thank you

But, while uploading CSV file, in the "timestamp" column, all dates are in "12/1/2019 12:30" format.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIEKx.png

Answer (score 0):

Import your CSV data with data-type support. Mongo import tool provides the option for that. Read more about importing with data type support [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-columnshavetypes)

Once you have imported properly, your queries would work. [Also take care of the date formats]